# Return the current release of blender on command line

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

Is there a way to poll the blender download website to return the current release candidates *paths* for blender.

At the time of this writing there is a release for both 2.79 and 2.80 so i would like a way to, from *command line*, find out that the downloads currently available are:

https://builder.blender.org/download/blender-2.79-e6acb4fba094-linux-glibc224-x86_64.tar.bz2
https://builder.blender.org/download/blender-2.80-430cf7e15eef-linux-glibc224-x86_64.tar.bz2

without having to scrape the download html page to extract the full *names*

Answer (score 1):

Using [akira's idea](https://superuser.com/a/47090/14566), you could use `wget --spider` to search the web page for links without downloading them. Then you could use something like awk or python to filter the output for the desired urls:

```
% wget -r -np --spider https://builder.blender.org/download/ 2>&1 | python -c "import sys; print(''.join([line.rsplit(' ', 1)[-1] for line in sys.stdin if all(term in line for term in ['http','linux'])]))"
https://builder.blender.org/download/blender-2.80-430cf7e15eef-linux-glibc224-x86_64.tar.bz2
https://builder.blender.org/download/blender-2.80-96f762500ef9-linux-glibc224-i686.tar.bz2
https://builder.blender.org/download/blender-2.79-e6acb4fba094-linux-glibc224-x86_64.tar.bz2
https://builder.blender.org/download/blender-2.79-e6acb4fba094-linux-glibc224-i686.tar.bz2
```

Comment: That's a bit webscrapy, I was hoping there was a more elegant way.  but i think/fear this is the way to go